# Testing Failure: ReferenceError: SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I recently tried to implement text to Speech in my project and decided to go with the plain javascript solution.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance)

I am currently using React@15.4.2 and enzyme@2.9.1.

Code:

```
export default class DummyComponent extends React.Component {
    /* */
    speak(text) {
        var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
        var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
        synth.speak(utterThis);
    }
    /* */
}
```

Everything works fine, but whenever I try to test my code I get the error in the title.

ExampleTest:

```
it('dummytest', function(done){
    const prop1 = 'foo';
    const prop2 = 'bar';
    const wrapper = shallow(<DummyComponent prop1 = {foo} prop2={bar}/>);
    expect(wrapper.html()).to.include("foobar");
    done(); 
});
```

> ReferenceError: SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined

It does not matter what I test in this class, all my tests for this component are failing, due to the fact that the Enzyme methods shallow, mount and render do not know *SpeechSynthesisUtterance*.

SpeechSynthesisUtterance actually comes from the typescript lib.
(typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts)

Things I already tried:

- Upgrading Enzyme to 3.2 (yields in exactly the same error)
- exporting the function
- using a tsconfig file to compile the lib.es6.d.ts

For the latter I tried a bunch of different settings and experimented with adding an "export {}" at the top of the file. This actually threw this error:

> node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5769,15): error TS2470: 'Symbol' reference does not refer to the global Symbol constructor object.

I have no experience with typescript, so I am running out of Ideas what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has the interface definition because the function is a **global** *in browsers*(check chrome and firefox) so you could just reference it. But for the node environment is not a global and thats why your test is failing, you should import it for test it, but i don't think that is available so if you want to test maybe you could create a stub version for the function

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks to your suggestion I found an npm package called proxyquire and this blog Post: https://engineering.thetrainline.com/use-proxyquire-to-mock-your-react-components-2b1e90ee2bac.

Answer (score 0):

An answer for this because Google lead me here and there was no fix...

The issue is that `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` is experimental technology, so it isn't supported everywhre. Your test suite doesnt support it, nor will [some browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=SpeechSynthesisUtterance).

Check for the API's existence in your code.

```js
if(window['speechSynthesis'] === undefined) {
    return; // Bail out
}
```

or

```js
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
    // Do something with Speech
}
```

In this case:

```js
export default class DummyComponent extends React.Component {
    /* */
    speak(text) {
        if(window['speechSynthesis'] === undefined) {
            return;
        }

        var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
        var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
        synth.speak(utterThis);
    }
    /* */
}
```